# 403 - Forbidden when I try to consume API with CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to get a list of products via user ID through an API.

I can usually get the product list via postman.

[image]

---

[image]

Here are screenshots of the postman.
In my code I try to get the list like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $http = new Client(['headers' => ['x-access-token' => 'Bearer ' . $session->read('Config.TOKEN')]]);
        $response = $http->get('http://localhost:8889/api/...', 
        [
            'user_id' => $session->read('Config.ID'),
        ]);
        
        var_dump($response);

        if ($response->isOk()) {
            $json = $response->getJSON();
            $this->set('json', $json["data"]);
            $this->set(compact('json'));
        }
    }
```

This is the return I get on the frontend using cakephp 4. Can you help me parse this?

[image]

Comment: Don't use `var_dump()`, use `debug()`. And why are you using the `Authorization` header when your working Postman request is using `x-access-token` instead?

Comment: I removed the var_dump and added debug. I don't use "Authorization" in postman. It does not recognize the token.

Comment: Well, let me ask the other way around then... why don't you use `x-access-token` in your code, when that is what appears to be working (at least in Postman)? And what exactly do you still need help with "parsing", now that the debug output is properly formatted in a readable fashion?